# Python - search a string in a file case insensitively

Tags: python, replace, case-insensitive

I wonder how I can search for some string in an XML file case insensitively.
I am using a python script to insert translation from Italian text file to strings XML file.

Here is the code I am using, but this does take case into account:

```
out_trans = open("italian.txt", "r").readlines()
f_xml_orig = open("strings.xml", "r").read()
f_xml_results = open("strings_italian.xml", "w")

for line_trans in out_trans:
    if line_trans:
        if '=' in line_trans:
            line_arr = line_trans.split('=')
            string_orig = line_arr[0].strip()
            string_trans = line_arr[1].strip()

            if string_trans:
                #translation exists
                if string_orig in f_xml_orig:
                    f_xml_orig = f_xml_orig.replace(string_orig, string_trans)

f_xml_results.write(f_xml_orig)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex module.

```
   line_arr = line_trans.split('=')
   string_orig = line_arr[0].strip()
   string_trans = line_arr[1].strip()

   if string_trans:        
       f_xml_orig = re.sub(string_orig, string_trans, f_xml_orig, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```